# Performance issue with Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB 4.2 to overcome lack of lookup pipeline aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am migrating my **MongoDB database** to **Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB** (version 4.2), and I am having a problem with the compatibility of the pipeline field in the `$lookup` aggregation on Cosmos DB.
This feature is [not yet supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42) by Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB.

I store small movies, and my objective is to get the movies of my friends, and to display the results, 4 per page, from the most recent to the oldest.

So I've updated my query to be compatible with Cosmos DB, but it takes so much time to have a response, 21 seconds with 305 documents as a result, i.e. 77 pages (305/4 = 76.25, round up).
Note that before, locally, the result took a few milliseconds to be obtained, and that all fields in the `friends` and `movies` collections are indexed (locally and in Cosmos DB).

Can you please help me?

Here's the query executed in Cosmos DB:

```
db.friends.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          ReceiverId: 2, // my ActorId
          Status: 1 // friend status (1 is accepted)
        },
        {
          RequesterId: 2, // my ActorId
          Status: 1 // // friend status (1 is accepted)
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      fieldResult: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [ "$ReceiverId", 2 ] // 2 is my ActorId
          },
          then: "$RequesterId",
          else: "$ReceiverId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "movies",
      localField: "fieldResult",
      foreignField: "ActorId",
      as: "movie"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$movie",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      movie: { $exists: true },
      "movie.State": 100,
      "movie.MovieActorRels.ActorId": 2
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      MovieId: "$movie.MovieId",
      Name: "$movie.Name",
      ActorId: "$movie.ActorId",
      Guid: "$movie.Guid",
      State: "$movie.State",
      WatchedTotalCount: "$movie.WatchedTotalCount",
      WatchedActorCount: "$movie.WatchedActorCount",
      RatedCount: "$movie.RatedCount",
      RatedTotalScore: "$movie.RatedTotalScore",
      AverageRating: "$movie.AverageRating",
      CreatedDate: "$movie.CreatedDate",
      PublishedDate: "$movie.PublishedDate",
      StarCoinsEarned: "$movie.StarCoinsEarned",
      MovieData: "$movie.MovieData",
      Complexity: "$movie.Complexity",
      CompetitionDate: "$movie.CompetitionDate",
      CompetitionId: "$movie.CompetitionId",
      CompetitionVotes: "$movie.CompetitionVotes",
      ActorClothesData: "$movie.ActorClothesData",
      MovieActorRels: "$movie.MovieActorRels",
      Scenes: "$movie.Scenes",
      ActorWatched: "$movie.ActorWatched"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "PublishedDate": -1 } },
  { $skip: 0 * 4 }, // 0 is the current page
  { $limit: 4 }
])
```

Here's the performance of the query above, executed in [Cosmos DB](https://sourceb.in/88UDsywkUG) and in [MongoDB](https://sourceb.in/AMcJ2rsA67).

Here's my previous query which generates the `MongoServerError: pipeline not supported` error if I run it on Cosmos DB:

```
db.friends.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          ReceiverId: 2, // my ActorId
          Status: 1 // friend status (1 is accepted)
        },
        {
          RequesterId: 2, // my ActorId
          Status: 1 // friend status (1 is accepted)
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      fieldResult: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [ "$ReceiverId", 2 ] // 2 is my ActorId
          },
          then: "$RequesterId",
          else: "$ReceiverId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "movies",
      localField: "fieldResult",
      foreignField: "ActorId",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            State: 100,
            "MovieActorRels.ActorId": 2 // my ActorId
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "movie"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$movie",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      movie: { $exists: true }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      MovieId: "$movie.MovieId",
      Name: "$movie.Name",
      ActorId: "$movie.ActorId",
      Guid: "$movie.Guid",
      State: "$movie.State",
      WatchedTotalCount: "$movie.WatchedTotalCount",
      WatchedActorCount: "$movie.WatchedActorCount",
      RatedCount: "$movie.RatedCount",
      RatedTotalScore: "$movie.RatedTotalScore",
      AverageRating: "$movie.AverageRating",
      CreatedDate: "$movie.CreatedDate",
      PublishedDate: "$movie.PublishedDate",
      StarCoinsEarned: "$movie.StarCoinsEarned",
      MovieData: "$movie.MovieData",
      Complexity: "$movie.Complexity",
      CompetitionDate: "$movie.CompetitionDate",
      CompetitionId: "$movie.CompetitionId",
      CompetitionVotes: "$movie.CompetitionVotes",
      ActorClothesData: "$movie.ActorClothesData",
      MovieActorRels: "$movie.MovieActorRels",
      Scenes: "$movie.Scenes",
      ActorWatched: "$movie.ActorWatched"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "PublishedDate": -1 } },
  { $skip: 0 * 4 }, // 0 is the current page
  { $limit: 4 }
])
```

Here's my `friends` scheme:

```
exports.friendModel = model(
  "friends",
  new Schema({
    RequesterId: Number,
    ReceiverId: Number,
    Status: Number
  })
);
```

Here's my `movies` scheme:

```
exports.movieModel = model(
  "movies",
  new Schema({
    MovieId: Number,
    Name: String,
    ActorId: Number,
    Guid: String,
    State: Number,
    WatchedTotalCount: Number,
    WatchedActorCount: Number,
    RatedCount: Number,
    RatedTotalScore: Number,
    AverageRating: Number,
    CreatedDate: Date,
    PublishedDate: Date,
    StarCoinsEarned: Number,
    MovieData: String,
    Complexity: Number,
    CompetitionDate: Date,
    CompetitionId: Number,
    CompetitionVotes: Array,
    ActorClothesData: String,
    MovieActorRels: Array,
    Scenes: Array,
    ActorWatched: Array
  })
);
```

Do I need to make any changes to the query to make it faster? Do I have to think of new schemes? I don't know where to start.
Note that I don't want to process the operations on the NodeJS side, Cosmos DB should return the result without me having to process it.

Thank you in advance for your help.